# Parallel.ForEach x of x

Tags: c#, wpf, parallel-processing

So I'm working in c# 4.0 WPF application and using parallel foreach loops to export data to a database using a database repository I created. I have got the export working with parallel foreach using a progress bar but would like to be able to give more in depth details of the progress like exporting item 5 of 25. The problem i've encountered is a obvious one, because it is running in parallel the counter does not work, i.e. the total will say something like

```
exporting 0 of 25
exporting 0 of 25
...
exporting 5 of 25
exporting 5 of 25
```

Can anyone give any guidence of how to get the behaviour working within a parallel loop like this:

```
int runningTotal = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(source, x =>
{
    Repository.Commit(x);
    runningTotal++;
    progressReporter.ReportProgress(() =>
    {
        //Progress bar update
        this.progressFile.Value++;
        this.lblProgress.Text = String
            .Format("Exporting Source {0} of {1}", runningTotal, source.Count)
    });
});
```

Hope this shows what I'm hoping to achieve.

Thanks

Comment: ProgressReporter class: http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com.es/2010/06/reporting-progress-from-tasks.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you're using the same data from multiple thread, you should protect it's access with a locking mechanism. It can be done easily by using the `lock` construct.

However, it might be a little too overkill for your need. As you're only incrementing a value, a simple `System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment` would work. On [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx).

```
int runningTotal = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(source, x =>
{
    Repository.Commit(x);
    Interlocked.Increment(ref runningTotal);
    progressReporter.ReportProgress(() =>
    {
        //Progress bar update
        Interlocked.Increment(ref this.progressFile.Value);
        this.lblProgress.Text = String
            .Format("Exporting Source {0} of {1}", runningTotal, source.Count)
    });
});
```

EDIT: I've made a sample in WPF.

Window.xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Click="Button_Click">Click me</Button>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="Progress: {0}/{1}">
                    <Binding Path="ProgressValue" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}" />
                    <Binding Path="ProgressMax" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int progressValue;
    public int ProgressValue
    {
        get { return (this.progressValue); }
        set { this.progressValue = value; this.raisePropertyChanged("ProgressValue"); }
    }

    public int ProgressMax
    {
        get { return (100); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void raisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            int counter = 0;

            Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(1, 100), i =>
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
                    this.ProgressValue = counter;
                Thread.Sleep(25);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I'm simply using bindings to display a string indicating the work progress. Everything is stored in the Window which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` to force bindings to refresh and display the updated value. It can easily be moved to it's own class which will implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for a cleaner code.

Comment: Why use runningTotal, just set Progress Maximum to source.Count and use progressFile.Value insted runningTotal

Comment: @Nekresh I tried the approach you suggested, unfortunately the display didn't seem to be updated till all the foreach's had completed and even then I got a output of Exporting Source 1 of 233, 30 of 233, 31 of 233... also the progress bar is a double which can't be incremented by the interlock.

Comment: @Stecya I have the running total because there are actually several foreach loops per file using the same file progress bar but I want a export progress for each one

Comment: @Manatherin When executing `Parallel.ForEach`, the executing thread will be blocked. If you do that on the UI thread, you won't be able to refresh the UI during that time (except by forcing `Refresh`).

Comment: @Nekresh The method containing the Parallel.ForEach calls are within a task and the progress reporter is a task scheduler for updating the UI, does the Parallel.ForEach block that? Also any ideas how to fix the out of order displaying (Or could you please explain how to force a refresh to see if this makes it refresh in order), Thanks

Comment: btw the progress reporter is the class at the bottom of this article http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/06/reporting-progress-from-tasks.html

Comment: @Manatherin Where did you create your `ProgressReporter` ? The ctor use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` which must be taken from the UI thread in order to work. If you create the `ProgressReporter` in the task thread, that won't work. Have you tried using directly `Window.Dispatcher.Invoke` for debugging purpose ?

Comment: @Nekresh Is it possible to bind the progress bar like that as well?

Comment: @Nekresh nevermind have just found how to bind ProgressBar with Value binding, thank you for all your help